# Как запретить доступ к серверу в обход nginx

Tags: nginx

Каким образом можно запретить обращение к серверу напрямую через порт? 
К примеру запросы идут на www.mysite.com:3000 в обход nginx, как это пресечь?

Comment: Операционная система какая ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

возможны как минимум два варианта:

1. если программа, слушающая порт 3000, поддаётся конфигурированию, то можно указать ей слушать не все доступные ip-адреса, а только какой-нибудь **внутренний** адрес из диапазона *127/8*, например, *127.0.0.1*, и соответствующим образом перенастроить *nginx* — проксировать обращения на *127.0.0.1:3000*.
2. если программа не поддаётся конфигурированию прослушиваемых ip-адресов, можно заблокировать с помощью *firewall-а* обращения к порту 3000 на внешнем интерфейсе, а *nginx* перенастроить, как и в предыдущем пункте.

Answer (score 1):

Поставить/настроить сетевой экран, который будет блокировать запросы к www.mysite.com:3000, если они не от nginx-а.